# Is there a way to represent an abstract week in R as a datetime type object, without referring to specific dates?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, lubridate

I am trying to graph a weekly schedule. It is similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816256/how-to-plot-time-interval-data-in-r-using-ggplot), but I want to show line segments that are like Monday 8pm to Tuesday 4am (indicating day and time).

The goal is to be able to plot multiple peoples' schedules together to see how much overlap there is in each functional group each day.

I haven't tried the below methods, but I believe that I could get where I want by either picking a starting date-time (a Sunday) and offset by days and time (ymd_hms("2023-07-02 00:00:00") + days(1) + hours(20)), then mask the date with axis scaling in ggplot, or I have to convert everything to durations (like the other method, but render the dates as durations) and then set the x-axis values manually.

Is there a way to render an abstract or relative date-time (like Monday, 8pm) or do I have to use one of my above workarounds?

Comment: This overview of different Gantt charting solutions might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550341/gantt-charts-with-r#29999300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest rewriting (augmenting) all of your timestamps to begin on the same "Sunday" (or whichever day) using `lubridate::floor_date`, and then counting into *that* week. For instance, some sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(starttime = as.POSIXct("2000-01-01", tz = "UTC") + 100*86400*runif(10), type = LETTERS[1:10])
dat$endtime <- dat$starttime + 86400*runif(10)
dat$weekstart <- lubridate::floor_date(dat$starttime, "weeks")
dat$start1 <- dat$weekstart[1] + difftime(dat$starttime, dat$weekstart, units = "secs")
dat$end1 <- dat$weekstart[1] + difftime(dat$endtime, dat$weekstart, units = "secs")
head(dat)
#             starttime type             endtime  weekstart              start1                end1
# 1 2000-04-01 11:32:04    A 2000-04-01 22:31:13 2000-03-26 2000-04-01 11:32:04 2000-04-01 22:31:13
# 2 2000-04-03 16:58:51    B 2000-04-04 10:14:22 2000-04-02 2000-03-27 16:58:51 2000-03-28 10:14:22
# 3 2000-01-29 14:44:05    C 2000-01-30 13:10:01 2000-01-23 2000-04-01 14:44:05 2000-04-02 13:10:01
# 4 2000-03-24 01:04:27    D 2000-03-24 07:12:16 2000-03-19 2000-03-31 01:04:27 2000-03-31 07:12:16
# 5 2000-03-05 04:11:21    E 2000-03-05 15:17:03 2000-03-05 2000-03-26 04:11:21 2000-03-26 15:17:03
# 6 2000-02-21 21:49:49    F 2000-02-22 20:23:26 2000-02-20 2000-03-27 21:49:49 2000-03-28 20:23:26

range(dat$starttime)
# [1] "2000-01-14 11:11:59 UTC" "2000-04-03 16:58:51 UTC"
range(dat$start1)
# [1] "2000-03-26 04:11:21 UTC" "2000-04-01 14:44:05 UTC"
```

We'll be using `start1` and `end1` for plotting. It doesn't matter if we based them all off of `dat$weekstart[1]` or `min(dat$weekstart)`, since the reference date is never shown, just the day-of-week.

Plot method:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(y = type)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start1, xend = end1, yend = type)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%a %H:%M")
```

[image: ggplot2 with weekday-only x-axis]

Some notes about this:

- while `floor_date` supports starting the week on arbitrary days of the week, unless you care, it doesn't matter: the "seconds of the week" is never shown; but if you really want to control it (perhaps for follow-on filtering?), then look into the `week_start=` argument.
- since we're keeping `x=` (and `xend=`) as proper `POSIXt` objects, we can use the native functionality of `scale_x_datetime`, including its `date_breaks=` (not shown, but could be something like `date_breaks="12 hours"` if desired).